# Can I create a "wildcard" bash alias that alters any command?

Tags: bash, alias, pipeline

The inspiration here is a prank idea, so try to look past the fact that it's not really useful...

Let's say I wanted to set up an alias in bash that would subtly change any command entered at the prompt into the same command, but ultimately piped through `tac` to reverse the final output. A few examples of what I'd try to do:

```
ls  --->  ls | tac
ls -la  --->  ls -la | tac
tail ./foo | grep 'bar'  --->  tail ./foo | grep 'bar' | tac
```

Is there a way to set up an alias, or some other means, that will append `| tac` to the end of each/every command entered without further intervention? Extra consideration given to ideas that are easy to hide in a bashrc. ;)

Comment: An alias is the wrong tool for this job. I'd use a DEBUG trap, myself.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't guaranteed to be side-effect-free, but it's probably a sane first cut:

```
reverse_command() {
  # C check the number of entries in the `BASH_SOURCE` array to ensure that it's empty
  # ...(meaning an interactive command).
  if (( ${#BASH_SOURCE[@]} <= 1 )); then
    # For an interactive command, take its text, tack on `| tac`, and evaluate
    eval "${BASH_COMMAND} | tac"
    # ...then return false to suppress the non-reversed version.
    false
  else
    # for a noninteractive command, return true to run the original unmodified
    true
  fi
}

# turn on extended DEBUG hook behavior (necessary to suppress original commands).
shopt -s extdebug

# install our trap
trap reverse_command DEBUG
```

Comment: The code works when entered _directly_ in an interactive shell, but if you put it into `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` (as one is likely to do for the prank to be effective), `reverse_command()` will see the _enclosing script_ in `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` and `${#BASH_SOURCE[@]}` will be _1_, so the conditional should read `(( ${#BASH_SOURCE[@]} == 1 ))` in that case.

Comment: As a minor point of interest, bash 3.2.53 produces broken output with `cat <<<$'line 1\nline 2\nline 3'`, because `$BASH_COMMAND` misreports it as `cat <<< $'\'line 1\nline 2\nline 3\''`. This has been fixed as of (at least) bash 4.3.30.

Comment: (Charles's comments relate to a since-deleted, mistaken diagnosis of mine. The `exit` comment relates to the fact that you won't be able to use it to exit such a shell, because the command will run in a subshell. Finally, a general tip: To make this code work on OSX and FreeBSD, use `tail -r` in lieu of `tac`.)

Comment: @mklement0, some great suggestions and feedback, thanks. I'm currently tweaking the comparison to `<= 1` for the reason given.

Comment: Thanks, Charles, I appreciate the follow-up. Come to think of it: do we even _need_ to check `BASH_SOURCE`, given that neither the `extedebug` options state, nor the definition of `reverse_command()`, nor the trap are inherited by _child_ shells, such as scripts?

Comment: I wasn't concerned about child shells as much as completion scripts and the like -- observed the hack interfering with them during testing.

Comment: ...completion _functions_, rather.

Comment: Thanks, good to know. Didn't know that programmable completion functions invariably add another element - the script that they are defined in - to  `${BASH_SOURCE[@]}`, from the perspective of the `DEBUG` trap.

Comment: The most notable side effect of this otherwise clever solution is that you seemingly can't pass the true exit code of the input command through, given that the function's exit code must be used to instruct the `DEBUG` trap as to what to do. In effect, all intercepted commands indicate success, regardless of whether they truly succeeded or not. Or is there a way around that?

Answer (score 1):

`bash` doesn't support modifying commands in this fashion. It does, however, let you redirect standard output for the shell itself, which every command will then inherit. Add this to `.bashrc`:

```
exec > >( tac )
```

Comment: Good call -- but how will you get conventional buffering behavior here?

Comment: (I'm also not certain that an outright statement of "doesn't support" is accurate; a DEBUG trap can run its own version of a command and then suppress the original).

Comment: This causes all output to disappear for me.

Comment: Oh, right -- because this is last-line-first, this won't work for unbounded sessions, because it *can't* print anything until it actually has a last line.

Comment: I didn't put a lot of thought into this, since it seems the goal is to play a prank on someone.

Comment: ...so, yeah. Can't just use one big unbounded `tac` invocation.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I was just about to add that "can't until the end" comment but you beat me to it.

Comment: While this approach won't work with `tac`, as stated in other comments, it would work with a variant prank: reversing the _characters_ on each output line (without changing the order of output lines): `exec > >( rev )`